# Using Basler Pylon SDK on MAC with Qt

Tags: macos, qt, qt5

I am trying to work on a Basler Camera (Pylon SDK) on mac using Qt. It seems as if, I have been able to successfully set up the pylon framework and have access to the necessary header files. I build it with some warnings. But When I even just create a Camera Object, it just crashes with the following error.

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   GenICam_3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0::RuntimeException

Here is my Pro File :

```
INCLUDEPATH += "/Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Headers/"
DEPENDPATH += "/Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Headers/"


INCLUDEPATH += "/Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Headers/GenICam"
DEPENDPATH += "/Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Headers/GenICam"

INCLUDEPATH += "/Library/Frameworks/"
DEPENDPATH += "/Library/Frameworks/"


INCLUDEPATH += "/Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework"
LIBS += -F"/Library/Frameworks/" -framework pylon
```

When I run on a parallel thread, it doesnt work either. 
The Code where it crashes is :

```
CInstantCamera camera( CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice());
```

Would you know what the problem is?

Thanks for your time.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the "GenICam_3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0:: RuntimeException" message text?

In the pylon for OS X distribution is also a sample for multiple camera grabbing (Grab_MultipleCameras)

You could also check for an answer in https://imaginghub.com/forums this is a platform like this for technics using machine vision.

Regards

Comment: Hi Bjorn thanks for your reply. I contacted Basler regarding this, It isnt an issue with XCode. In fact it builds with Qt as well. It only falters at the runtime. I have raised the bug with them and they should get back to me asap on that. Thanks :)